# ScrollView stuck when keyboard open & cursor in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a `ScrollView` with some widgets in it, amongst them an `EditText`. When I write a couple of lines in the `EditText` (`id:message`), I can't scroll the `ScrollView` all the way up to the top, it is stuck until I close the soft keyboard. After that, if I go into the `EditText` again and write another couple of lines, this doesn't happen anymore. This only happens on Android 4.x, not on 2.3. 
How can I prevent my `ScrollView` from getting stuck?

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/ihr_name"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/ihre_email"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" >

            <asco.asco.spinnerbuttonlib.spinnerbutton.StaticSpinnerbutton
                android:id="@+id/startDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/starterror"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" >

            <asco.asco.spinnerbuttonlib.spinnerbutton.StaticSpinnerbutton
                android:id="@+id/endDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/enderror"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" >

            <asco.asco.spinnerbuttonlib.spinnerbutton.StaticSpinnerbutton
                android:id="@+id/xy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adulterror"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <asco.asco.spinnerbuttonlib.spinnerbutton.StaticSpinnerbutton
            android:id="@+id/tre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Message: "
            android:textAppearance="@style/StandardTextBold"
            android:textColor="@color/myorange" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/ihre_nachricht"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:text="@string/contact_message" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/pflichtfelder"
            android:textAppearance="@style/SmallText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send"
            style="@style/ButtonTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Senden" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/contact_datenschutz"
            android:textAppearance="@style/SmallText" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here's a screenshot of the stuck layout (not too interesting probably):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input options are set to pan (keep the view we are inputting visible)

add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your activity declaration in the manifest